# Are generic properties that might return arrays acceptable?

Tags: c#, generics

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0fss9skc(v=vs.120).aspx, properties should not return arrays. How does this interact with generics? If an array is an allowable type for a generic, should I be making functions like `T GetValue()` and `SetValue(T value)` rather than `T Value { get; set; }`?

Comment: Creating methods to get/set the value isn't really doing anything to mitigate the effects described in the reasoning for the rule.

Comment: Never really thought about this. I've always returned an array when  I didn't want my internal collection to be added to or removed from. Maybe, I should start using ReadOnlyCollection.

Comment: @Servy: While true enough, most programmers think a bit before they use a construct like GetValueT()[x] in a loop.

Comment: @RobinHood70 Are you actually copying the entire array here?

Comment: @Servy: I'm not sure I understand your question. In point of fact, the function that prompted the question is internal and I know for a fact that I'll never use it as described, but I was curious to know what (if any) workarounds were considered appropriate for the general case.

Comment: @RobinHood70 No guidelines like these are going to be applicable in the general case.  They're *always* going to be context dependent.

Comment: @Servy `Creating methods to get/set the value` mitigates the effect of `users will not understand the adverse performance implications of calling such a property`.

Comment: @Rawling [You're assuming that the member will have adverse performance effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001505/are-generic-properties-that-might-return-arrays-acceptable?noredirect=1#comment40724190_26001505).  It's not clear that that's the case.  It looks like the structure simply isn't going to end up being copied here.

Comment: @Servy I'm not assuming anything, I'm just quoting CA1819 in its own defense.

Comment: @Rawling Well, the statement that you quoted is dependent on the earlier statement that the array would need to be copied.  The statement you quoted only applies here if the OP is copying the values in the array in these methods, rather than copying the reference.

Comment: I see not problem with using something like `List<int[]>` where the indexer returns an `int[]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This rule is not absolute. Understand where it comes from: A property returning an array realistically needs to make a copy of it so that the caller can mutate its copy and not reach into object internal state.

If you are dealing with generic code that generic code does not know anything about the concrete `T`. It does not depend on its internal structure. Therefore, adhering to this rule does not help. Passing arrays in and out of generic code is totally acceptable.

Practical example: A `List<int[]>`.

In addition to that, Servy notes correctly that creating methods to get/set the value isn't really doing anything to mitigate the effects described in the reasoning for the rule.